# PLS-00363: expression 'i' cannot be used as an assignment target

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE or replace stored procedure test123 as
DECLARE
    i   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        INSERT INTO test123 ( empl_number ) VALUES ( i );
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

i am trying to create this stored procedure and i am getting the following error "expression 'I' cannot be used as an assignment target"

Can anyone throw some insight on what could be the reason for this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Not about the error, but you could simply do `INSERT INTO test123( empl_number )  select level from dual connect by level <= 10`  instead of loops.

Answer (score 5):

You have declared `i` as a variable twice. First as a local variable and second in your loop, which shadows the local variable.

You are trying to assign a value to the loop variable - which is not permitted (you do not need to increment the loop variable; this will happen automatically)

Also, you should not include the `STORED` or `DECLARE` words as they are invalid syntax.

So you could simply write it as:

```
CREATE or replace procedure test123 as
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        INSERT INTO table_name ( empl_number ) VALUES ( i );
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you don't need to declare a variable to use it in a `FOR` loop. If you try to, it's actually not the same variable, even if it has the same name.

From the documentation for
[FOR Loop index](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-7E1AC17C-83EB-422C-98F4-2F13D9B694F4):

> The index of a `FOR LOOP` statement is implicitly declared as a variable of type `PLS_INTEGER` that is local to the loop. The statements in the loop can read the value of the index, but cannot change it. Statements outside the loop cannot reference the index. After the `FOR LOOP` statement runs, the index is undefined.

The two `'i'`s in your example are different variables. You can refer to the top-level one by prefixing it with the procedure name.

Outside the loop, by default `i` refers to the procedure-level variable. Within the loop, `i` refers to the loop index.

```
create or replace procedure test123 as
    i  number := 0;
begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        test123.i := test123.i + 10;

        dbms_output.put_line('Loop index i = ' || i);
        dbms_output.put_line('Procedure-level variable i = ' || test123.i);
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('After loop: i = ' || i);
end;
```

Output:

```
Loop index i = 1
Procedure-level variable i = 10
Loop index i = 2
Procedure-level variable i = 20
Loop index i = 3
Procedure-level variable i = 30
Loop index i = 4
Procedure-level variable i = 40
Loop index i = 5
Procedure-level variable i = 50
After loop: i = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown above the loop control variable `i` is not assignable, and within the loop it "hides" the declared variable 'i'.

Comment: how do i then increment the loop counter value?

Comment: You don't. The loop variable will increment from 1 to 10 automatically. Which `i` are you trying to affect, the one defined by `i   NUMBER := 0` or the one defined by `FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP`? Those are *two different variables*.